# TypeError save() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have error like  Type Error save() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given) in Django project.

view.py file

```
class DealsForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['title','description','category','price','sale_price','slug','active','update_defaults','user']
        exclude = ('user',)
```

model.py file

```
class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True,max_length=200)
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category, null=True, blank=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=100, default=29.99)
    sale_price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=100,\
                                            null=True, blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    update_defaults = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)   

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('title', 'slug')

    def get_price(self):
        return self.price

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("single_product", kwargs={"slug": self.slug})

    def save(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        obj = super(DealsForm, self).save(commit=False, *args, **kwargs)
        obj.user = request.user 
        obj.save()
```

Can you solve this problems ?

Comment: Please post the full stacktrace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are not passing the `request` object when calling `.save()`.  You need to pass the `request` object also according to the definition of `save()`.

Also, please check your `.save()` function as you are calling `super()` with `DealsForm` class argument in the `Product` model class.

**EDIT:**

Since you just want to set the `user` on the `product` object, you can just do the following instead:

```
def my_view(request):
    ...
    product = my_deals_form.save(commit=False) # get the product instance
    product.user = request.user # set the user on the product
    product.save() # save the object
```

You don't need to override the `save()` method. Just call the model form instance with `commit=False` argument, set the user on `product` object and then save the object.

Comment: I put that code but still get that error                                                                                                               def save(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            obj = super(DealsForm, self).save(commit=False, *args, **kwargs)
            obj.user = request.user 
            obj.save(request)

Comment: Why are you calling `super(DealsForm, ` in `Product` class? That code should be in `DealsForm` class.

Comment: Updated the ans to include the code. Hope it helps.